# How to store bulbs in order to plant them when appropriate?

Tags: bulbs

There is a sale right now for lavender mountain lilies & daffodils, etc.  I have been reading that at least the lavender mountain lilies do best if planted in fall or early spring.

I was wondering is it possible to purchase the bulbs now (in late spring) and store them (I am supposing they should be stored somewhere dark and cool and plant them in fall?  If so what is the best way to store them?

Not sure if it helps but I live on Vancouver Island (zone: i think it is zone 8b).

Comment: Tulips will not bloom in zone 8 in TX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider where they store themselves when planted in the landscape and left.

You could fool around with trying to store them out of the ground, or you could just plant them in the (dark, cool) ground and have (IME) better odds of success.

Comment: It took me a couple of seconds to understand your suggestion...then got a chuckle out of it!  That' brilliant.  Thanks I'm a total beginner...your advice makes total sense.